# How to prevent dangling pointer when std::unique is used?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, unique, containers

How can I delete a pointer in a vector after std::unique is called?

For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int bar) : mBar(bar) {}
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "~dtor\n"; }

    int mBar;
};

bool SortFunc(Foo * right, Foo * left) { return right->mBar < left->mBar; }

// Should I 'delete left;' in case of equality?
bool CompareFunc(Foo * right, Foo * left)
{
    return right->mBar == left->mBar;
}

// NOTE: In my code, vector is initialized in another class which I cannot modify.
void InitializeList(std::vector<Foo *> & fooList)
{
    Foo * firstFoo = new Foo(1);
    Foo * secondFoo = new Foo(2);
    // This pointer will not be in vector anymore after std::unique is called!
    Foo * thirdFoo = new Foo(1);
    Foo * forthFoo = new Foo(4);

    fooList.push_back(firstFoo);
    fooList.push_back(secondFoo);
    fooList.push_back(thirdFoo);
    fooList.push_back(forthFoo);
}

int main()
{
    { // Block exists to see if Foo::dtor is called.
    std::vector<Foo *> fooList;
    InitializeList(fooList);

    std::sort(fooList.begin(), fooList.end(), SortFunc);

    std::vector<Foo *>::iterator itrResult = fooList.end();
    // Pointer to thirdFoo is dangling after std::unique is called.
    itrResult = std::unique(fooList.begin(), fooList.end(), CompareFunc);
    fooList.erase(itrResult, fooList.end());

    // ... Other operations and clean up code.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Iterate from `itrResult` to `fooList.end()` and call delete on each element *before* calling `fooList.erase()`?

Comment: In your example you can also just store `Foo` in vectors by value.

Comment: chris, dragonroot: I cannot modify InitializeList section of the code.

Comment: juanchopanza: std::unique performs a different allocation on vector of pointers. Actually, itrResult++ points to forthFoo and if you erase it, forthFoo will be deleted.

Comment: I cannot make any sense out of your last comment.

Comment: juanchopanza: When I debug code, I can see that std::unique does not swap forthFoo with thirdFoo. So forthFoo at the end of the vector still remains in list after std::unique.

Comment: I'm confused, according to [the documentation of `std::unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/), it removes only *consecutive* duplicates. That means that in your case, it shouldn't remove anything.

Comment: @svick it does, because of the call to `std::sort`. See [here](http://ideone.com/llBeqZ).

Comment: don't hang your pointers around...

Answer (score 5):

You can insulate yourself from the poorly implemented `InitializeList` by immediately wrapping its result in smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;
{
  std::vector<Foo *> foo_ptrs;
  InitializeList(foo_ptrs);
  foos.assign(foo_ptrs.begin(), foo_ptrs.end());
}
```

Now you can call `std::unique` on `foos` and know that nothing will leak.  If you're doing this often a wrapper function might be a good idea:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> get_foos() {
  std::vector<Foo *> foo_ptrs;
  InitializeList(foo_ptrs);
  return {foo_ptrs.begin(), foo_ptrs.end()};
}
```

Comment: C++11 is not used in our project.

Comment: @MuratEnder, There's still Boost and *cough* `std::auto_ptr` *cough*

Comment: Even if it is stated that "The function shall not modify any of its arguments." in std::unique documentation, what happens if I delete left pointer in CompareFunc when right and left are equal? When I try that option, it seems to perform well, but it looks like hackin :?

Comment: @MuratEnder I think that's a terrible hack. It would be much not to use `unique()` and write custom function for that.

Comment: That s the another point I am looking for. Why std::unique should not modify its arguments? I had no trouble in that modification for `delete left;`

Answer (score 0):

As juanchopanza mentioned, you need to call `delete` explicitly on duplicate elements.

The leak is here:

```
   fooList.erase(itrResult, fooList.end());
```

The `erase` will simply remove the pointers between the two iterators. You have to call `delete` on them first.